# What can be use case for defining an object with extends Function2[Int, Int] in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How is below object `sum` different from a function `f(i: Int, j:Int) = i + j`

From what I know functions are traits and each time we declare a function an object of that trait with accordingly defined apply method is created. But I am not able to understand what special purpose could an object definition like below serve.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

```
 object sum extends Function2[Int, Int, Int]{
    def apply(first: Int, second: Int) = {
      first + second
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a value; `f` is not, it can just be converted to a value, and if it's used in several places it will be converted multiple times, which can have a (likely very small) effect on performance. However, I don't think there are any advantages compared to `val sum = (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j` (or if it needs to be at top level, `object A { val sum = (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j }`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of features methods have that function literals don't:

- methods can be generic, function literals can't,
- methods can have an implicit parameter list, function literals can't,
- methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, function literals can't,
- methods can have repeated parameters, function literals can't.

So, by defining the `apply` method explicitly instead of using the function literal syntactic sugar, you get access to all of these.

Also, you can add additional methods and/or fields.

However, your example use none of these, so really, there is no point in using the explicit syntax.

Actually, there is *one* difference: in

```
val sum = (first: Int, second: Int) => first + second
```

`sum` is a `val`, whereas in your example, it's an `object`.

Note also, that the code you posted:

```
def f(i: Int, j:Int) = i + j
```

is *not* a function, it's a method! My answer applies to the difference between a function literal and an explicitly defined instance / subtype of `FunctionN`, *not* to methods.

Comment: If you want to use something you described in the first paragraph, why extend `FunctionN` then? Why not to use an arbitrary class with `apply`?

Comment: Because you want to pass it to something which expects a `FunctionN`, e.g. `Seq.map`. AFAIK, most methods that expect a function are hard-wired to `FunctionN` instead of a structural type with `apply` (unlike Ruby, Python, or Java).

Comment: But `Seq.map` won't expect your custom `apply` (you will have to define the mandatory one anyway), which kind of defeats the purpose?